# Why does my Eclipse Helios debugging hand when stepping over Path.register(WatchService, Kind<?>...)?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have code like this in a Junit 4 class:

```
Path dir = Paths.get("/tmp/testDir");
dir.toFile().mkdir();
WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
dir.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
    StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);
```

When I try to step over the last statement in the Eclipse Helios debugging perspective, the relevant thread indicates that it's "Stepping" and never returns. Why?

The same behavior (hanging on the Path.register() call) apparently also occurs when I try the Maven command "mvn test" to execute the Junit class (at least that hypothesis is consistent with the failure of the class that I see).

Here's my JVM:

```
$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What happens when you run the mvn test task from the command line?

Comment: I was executing the "mvn test" from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of answering my own question, I've learned the following things about the Path.register() method: 1) it apparently won't return if all other threads in the JUnit test are suspended; and 2) it doesn't execute quickly enough to catch the first file that the JUnit test creates. Consequently, the Eclipse debugging hung and the Maven test failed at exactly the same point -- but for different reasons.